# how to extract used licenses from a java project

Tags: java, licensing, libraries

As many other people I used several opensource libraries in my project. Most of them are used as JAR files. I now would like to create a list of the used licenses (e.g. Apache, GPL, LGPL, Mozilla Public License,...)
some jars contain a license.txt but most of them not. Could you please recommend me a software or method, how i could extract such "used licenses"-information out of my java project?
Thanking you very much in advance for helping me

BR

Shane

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get the sources of all the open source used in the your project may be from internet or from author copyrighted.

manual approach :

1. Where the license.txt file present-

   - Get license name from License.txt file
   - Note the licenses and related open source component in list-of-license.txt file
2. where the license.txt file not-present-

   - get the source code
   - analysis and check in source code containing license.
     e.g if apache-aop.jar does not have any license.txt file, get the source code from internet.
     Note the licenses and related open source component in list-of-license.txt file

another approach with the help of open source scanning software tool:

You can use any other open source scanning tool which will list all the open source component and licenses possible matches used inside the project and you can make use of it.

open source tool list reference,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis

Thanks,
Sandeep